# loop cut and slide to all edges selects?

Tags: edges

Its possible to do loop cut and slide on 2 or 10 or 50 edges selected??? LIKE THE EXAMPLE

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The best way I can think to do it would be to delete all but one segment and to use the array modifier to get each repetition.  That way, to do a loop cut on each edge, you just have to do it on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way of cuts:D**

1. select edge ring.
2. subdivide it and choose the number of cuts.

[image]

[image]

[image]